# Allowing For Multiple Images in Product Gallery for One Attribute

Tags: magento

If you edit a product and browse to the media gallery, you will notice that each type of image (Base, small, thumbnail) is a radio button. Furthermore, if you create your own product attribute and assign it to the product, it too is a radio button.

The intended functionality I would like is to upload many images and assign it to that attribute. I am creating a gallery on product view pages, and each product has an arbitrary amount of images.

I would like to know if there is an easy way to do it, and if not, what the best solution would be. I am running Magento 1.6.0 for this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upload images and do not assign them as base/small/thumb, then Magento will automatically create an image gallery for you on the product page. you could also extend the `catalog/product/list.phtml` to display a gallery on the category and search results listing if you wanted.

So, AFAIK, there's no need for you to change the application functionality in the way that you describe.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Day, you have saved my day. It was not immediately clear that I could do this and now it seems very obvious. Thanks.

Comment: @jonathan, I have one additional image attribute for specific purpose. that I want to get on frontend as array for example my attribute code is "specification" and I want to add multiple images in specification attribute. How can I acheive this. Thank you

Comment: @shivam please post a new question. StackOverflow does not work like a forum. thx